# Using JSP 2.0 tags in Facelets

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, facelets, jsf-2

Is someone using Facelets with JSP 2.0 tags? How to add tag library to xhtml page? In JSP I used:

```
<% taglib prefix="example" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/my" %> 
and : <example:sample/>
```

How can I do the same in facelets with JSP 2.0 tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Facelet XHTML you would add a taglib in the following way:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
```

Comment: Allan I know that I can use xmlns to include external library, but I need to write my own tags (with scirptlets or another java code) and I have to put this write code like a tag in xhtml page. Can I do that? In JSP pages it was very simple, but I don't know the Facelets very good.

Comment: Certainly, it works in the same way. Once you have created your tags in Facelets, you can import them using xmlns. I've got a simple example of creating and using a custom Facelets tag here: http://blogs.i2m.dk/allan/2008/03/18/example-of-using-custom-facelet-tags/

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something like this.

Answer (score 2):

Facelets and JSP are mutually exlusive - they are two different view technologies.

Some JSP tags are ported to facelets, using the facelets tag library descriptors.

So if you want to define facelets tags, add the appropriate descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
```

That's "http://java.sun.com/**jsp**/jstl/core" or it won't work.

Comment: The `/jsp`-less URI applies to Facelets 1.x only.